# I can't add a button in a table in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I want to (view) button in the table but it make this error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 165 while parsing near '...2021",
> "view": <button type="submit...'
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 165 while parsing near '...2021",
> "view": <button type="submit...'
> at JSON.parse ()

This is `IncomingMessagesTable.js`:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import { IncomingMessagesColumns } from './IncomingMessagesColumns';
import IncomingMessagesData from './IncomingMessagesData.json';
import '../Table.css'

export const IncomingMessagesTable = () => {
  const columns = useMemo(() => IncomingMessagesColumns, [])
  const data = useMemo(() => IncomingMessagesData, [])
  const tableInstance = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  })

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = tableInstance

   return (
     <div>
          
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  );
}
onLoadMore = () => {
  this.setState({
    usersToShow: this.state.usersToShow + 1,
  });
};
export default IncomingMessagesTable;
```

And this is `IncomingMessagesColumns.json`:

```
    export const IncomingMessagesColumns = [
  {
    Header : "اسم المرسل",
    accessor : "senderName"
  },
  {
    Header : "نوع المرسل",
    accessor : "senderType"
  },
  {
    Header : "عنوان الرسالة",
    accessor : "messageAddress"
  },
  {
    Header : "تاريخ الرسالة",
    accessor : "dateOfMessage"
  },
  {
    Header : "قراءة",
    accessor : "view",
  
  }
]
```

And this is `IncomingMessagesData.json`:

```
[
  {
    "senderName": "أحمد",
    "senderType": "معلم",
    "messageAddress": "رسالة إلى أولياء أمور الطلاب",
    "dateOfMessage": "11/12/2021",
    "view": <button type="submit">عرض الرسالة</button>
  }
]
```

Comment: Also, I assume `IncomingMessagesColumns.json` is actually`IncomingMessagesColumns.js` as the contents your showing is not JSON either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"view": <button type="submit">عرض الرسالة</button>
```

This is not a valid data for JSON. You can wrap it in double quote like this

```
"view": "<button type="submit">عرض الرسالة</button>"
```

Now you can add string HTML to your code like this

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<button type="submit">عرض الرسالة</button>'}}/>
```

Comment: When i write it in double quote, it consider it a string, and write this sentence: <button type="submit">عرض الرسالة</button>
in the table, but i want to add a button not text.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It is succcess, thanks.

Comment: @Batool consider giving an up vote